# Box slider's box controls not working

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am using two list of images using boxslider to be displayed in the same space 
Basically i am initializing one boxslider and when all the images have rolled one time i am initializing the second boxslider and destroying the first box slider using slider.destroySlider(); 
The error i am getting is when both box sliders have moved exactly once , the box controls are not working at all and even the goleft and go right button is not working .. here is a code snippet

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="boxSliderContainer1">
       <ul id="bxslider2">
        <li><img src="goo.png"></li>
        <li><img src="goo2.png"></li>
        <li><img src="goo3.png"></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="boxSliderContainer2">
       <ul id="bxslider">
        <li><img src="goo4.png"></li>
        <li><img src="goo5.png"></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

and some part of my js

```
$('#bxslider2').bxSlider({
          auto: false,
          speed: 500,
          pause: 10000,
          onSlideNext : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
            if(oldIndex==2){
                services_slider();
            }
         }
      }
      );
$('#bxslider1').bxSlider({
          auto: false,
          speed: 500,
          pause: 10000,
          onSlideNext : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
            if(oldIndex==2){
                products_slider();
            }
         }
      }
      );
function services_slider(){
    $(".bxsliderContainer2").css('display','none');
    $(".bxsliderContainer").css('display','block');
    $('#bxslider').bxSlider({
          auto: true,
          speed: 500,
          pause: 10000,
          captions: true,
          onSlideNext : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
            if(oldIndex == 1)
                product_slider();
      }});
    slider = $('#bxslider2').bxSlider();
    slider.destroySlider();
}
function product_slider(){
    $(".bxsliderContainer").css('display','none');
    $(".bxsliderContainer2").css('display','block');
    $('#bxslider2').bxSlider({
          auto: true,
          speed: 500,
          pause: 10000, 
          onSlideNext : function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
            if(oldIndex == 2)
                services_slider();}
      });
    slider = $('#bxslider').bxSlider();
    slider.destroySlider();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried just hiding the divs instead of destroying the sliders , but  still i am getting the same error

Comment: when i used Reloadslider() instead of destroyslider() it started working